# How to create a file in a specified path in Ubuntu using C#

Tags: c#, linux, docker, ubuntu, copy-paste

I have a program which runs as Linux based container in Ubuntu system. The project is written using .NetCore libraries.

From my 'root' directory in Ubuntu I can set the path as below and see existing file there

```
root@user: cd /var/abc/modules/moduleOne/files
```

Inside that path a file exists named 'logs.txt'

How to copy that file and paste with different name?

I was trying as below

```
var destination = "//var//abc//modules//moduleOne//files//copy.txt";
var source = Path.Combine("//var//abc//modules//moduleOne//files", "logs.txt");
File.Copy(source, destination);
```

It throws error in runtime as below

```
Exception occurred Could not find a part of the path '/var/abc/modules/moduleOne/files/logs.txt'
```

Comment: Why do you write your slashes 2 times? This is only required if you use backslashes cause you must escape them.

Comment: first check that file exist and have required permissions "docker exec -it [replace this with container name or id] ls -lah /var/abc/modules/moduleOne/files" . second try whitout those double slashes (in you code) . My guess is a matter of user. In your host machine , u ussually use your name user, while in docker you can specify a user either on image or container.

Comment: I mistakenly written double slash. Indeed single slash works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following code inside a docker linux container and it works:

```
File.WriteAllText("/test.txt", "Test");
string destination = "/var/copy.txt";
string source = Path.Combine("/", "test.txt");
System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination);
```